# Footer placement in LaTeX

Tags: positioning, header-footer, koma-script

I'm trying to write a footer in my document. I'm using the following command

```
\cofoot{\so{\Large\Letter} abc@def.com \ {\Large\Telefon} (+12) 345-678-9101}
```

How to manually place the footer in the right place ? I mean, how to specify the exact spacing ?

Comment: Are you meaning the vertical position of the footer?

Answer (score 2):

[`KOMA-script`](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) offers a range of footer (and header) specifications via `scrpage2`. For example, see the [`KOMA-script` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/scrguien.pdf) (Chapter **4 Adapting Page Headers and Footers with `scrpage2`**, p 110 onward):

[image]

`\cofoot{<stuff>}`, as in your code snippet, puts `<stuff>` `c`entered on `o`dd pages. For "exact (horizontal) spacing", you can use a variety of methods, depending on your needs:

- a fixed length `<len>` from the left margin: Use

  ```
  \lfoot{\hspace*{<len>}<stuff>}
  ```
- a fixed length `<len>` from the right margin: Use

  ```
  \rfoot{<stuff>\hspace*{<len>}}
  ```
- a proportionate ratio from the left/right margin: Use

  ```
  \cfoot{\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\mbox{}\hfill<stuff>\hfill\hfill\mbox{}}}
  ```

  This will place stuff with a 1:2 ratio spread across `\textwidth`.

Other choices are also available.